# Microsoft Visual studio is unable to load this document

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to open a package in SSIS 2012 which is created in SSIS 2014.

How i can get rid of this error?

See the error below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't. See [the interoperability and coexistence guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577(v=sql.120).aspx):

> If you save the change to the package, the package is permanently upgraded. Once saved in the format that SQL Server 2014 Integration Services uses, packages can no longer be opened in the corresponding SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012 version of Business Intelligence Development Studio, nor run by the corresponding SQL Server 2008 Integration Services or SQL Server 2012 Integration Services tools.

Answer (score 0):

Currently SSDT BI 2014 for Visual Studio 2013 does not support SSIS packages for SQL Server 2012. However a workaround which might be helpful to you is available at - 
http://vaniecastro.com/2015/02/26/how-to-downgrade-sql-server-integration-services-2014-packages-to-2012/